# Trying to read 32-bit unsigned integer in Tcl using binary scan

Tags: tcl

I'm sure I'm doing something very stupid but can't seem to get this simple item figured out. I'm using the native-messaging API in a browser extension to pass a JSON string to a Tcl script. I have this working in C using `uint32_t` but can't get the 32 bit unsigned integer that is prefixed to the message read in Tcl. I know that it is reading something because I wrote the `$len` to file and I'm pretty sure it sits and waits for the procedure `coread` to read more bytes than there are in the message. I've tried `Iu` and `iu` in addition to `nu` in the `binary scan` command. Would you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Should it matter if the messages include multi-byte characters such as Hebrew and Greek?

Added later: I'm pretty sure it's the multi-byte characters because the code works until they are included. But why would that be? Do not the browser and Tcl both count the length of the message in bytes? Whatever is happening, the length determined in Tcl exceeds the length that Tcl reads.

Thank you.

Doc. reads:

> Each message is serialized using JSON, UTF-8 encoded and is preceded
> with an unsigned 32-bit value containing the message length in native
> byte order.

In C the form for listening for incoming message on stdin is:

```
int listen( void ) {
   uint32_t msg_len;
   while ( fread( &msg_len, sizeof msg_len, 1, stdin ) == 1 ) {
     char *buf = malloc( msg_len ); 
     if ( !buf ) {
     }
     else if ( fread( buf, sizeof *buf, msg_len, stdin ) != msg_len ) {
     }
     else {
       // Read the full messsage.
     }
     fflush( stdout );
     free( buf );
   }
  return 0;
}
```

In Tcl I'm been trying:

```
proc coread {reqBytes} {
  set ::extMsg {}
  set remBytes $reqBytes
  while {![chan eof stdin]} {
    yield
    append ::extMsg [set data [read stdin $remBytes]]
    set remBytes [expr {$remBytes - [string length $data]}]
    if {$remBytes == 0} {
      return $reqBytes
    }
  }
  throw {COREAD EOF} "Unexpected EOF"
}

proc ExtRead {} {
  chan event stdin readable coro_stdin
  while {1} {
    if { [coread 4] != 4 || [binary scan $::extMsg nu len] != 1 } {
      exit
    }
    set ::extMsg {}
    if { [coread $len] != $len } {
      exit
    }
    # Read full message.
  }
}

proc Listen {} {
  # Listening on stdin
  set ::forever 1
  coroutine coro_stdin ExtRead
  vwait forever
}

set extMsg {}
Listen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly figured it out. The problem is almost certainly due to multi-byte characters. With the default stdin encoding setting, Tcl counts each character as 1, while the length you got is probably indicating the bytes, not the characters. If the JSON string includes crlf line endings, that would be another cause for discrepancies.

The solution is to configure stdin to binary and then apply the utf-8 decoding later:

```
fconfigure stdin -translation binary
coread 4
binary scan $::extMsg nu len
coread $len
puts [encoding convertfrom utf-8 $::extMsg]
```

Not using binary translation could also mess up your length. For example: If the length of the message is 269, it would come out as 266. This is because the \r gets turned into a \n, changing 0x10d into 0x10a.

Comment: I would have written the `coread` proc to return the string, rather than the requested length. That would avoid using a global variable and could make the code more straight forward. But that's not the point of your question.

Comment: Thank you. This worked to get the `coread` to complete but it resultedin `\t\n` all throughout the document such that they appeared as text in Kate and when viewed as HTML in a browser; and `tDOM` could not parse the document.  I tried `chan configure stdin -buffering full -blocking 0 -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf` (which I should've known from othere experiments) and it appears to be working fine and `tDOM` can parse it. But this answer is what I needed to get me started; and, most likely, works but I was doing something wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding returning the string from `coread`, I get a bit confused about that. Is it not passing by value rather than reference such that the entire message is copied? Does it matter? I read about passing dictionaires around between procedures; so, it seems that passing-by-value is not avoided in Tcl. My first thought is pass a pointer; but I'm just a novice and don't see professional code; and I appreciate the comment because I can use all the critcism and guidance I can get. Thanks.

Comment: Passing a value around in Tcl is just a matter of passing a pointer to a Tcl_Obj structure. A reference counter keeps track of how many users there are of a single value. Nothing gets copied, unless something wants to modify a shared value. But by that time the `coread` proc has already ended, the local variable has vanished and the reference counter has been decremented, making the value unshared once again.

Comment: JSON does not allow control characters, including tabs and newlines, in strings. So probably the `\t\n` you see are literally there. You really should use binary translation if the specified length is in bytes. If you want to turn crlf newlines into Tcl's standard newlines, apply `string map [list \r\n \n] $str` afterwards. But I don't think that's what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know enough about it to be sure but it apppears that `\t\n\r` characters are escaped but instead of being recognized as controls when read again they are treated as text. If a web page is sent to Tcl and written to a file, then opened in a browser or Kate, all the escaped characters appear as text.  More accurately, in Kate they all appear as text and in the browser many appear as text. But if the encoding is iso8859 that doesn't happen. I'm not trying to disagree with you; I'm sure you know this stuff. Just explaining what happens here. Likely I'm doing it wrong still.