# Reading Hebrew in JSON via native-messaging API and writing to file but Hebrew looks wrong in the file?

Tags: tcl

I'm using this code to read messages received from a browser extension via the native-messaging API. Fortunately, it works and reads all the data. Unfortunately, I'm doing something wrong or failing to do something right (if there is a difference there) and when the data is written to the file, it appears that the multi-byte characters (Hebrew, at the moment) are being written as individual bytes.

Would you please tell me what needs to be done before writing `[dict get $msg doc]` to the file? `$msg` is a big string of HTML. Am I configuring stdin incorrectly or does the data being written to file need to be encoded?

Instead of seeing Hebrew, the file shows items like this ×”Ö¸×Ö¸Ö½×¨Ö¶×¥×.

According to the MDN [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging#app_side) the incoming message is:

> On the application side, you use standard input to receive messages
> and standard output to send them.
>
> Each message is serialized using JSON, UTF-8 encoded and is preceded
> with an unsigned 32-bit value containing the message length in native
> byte order.

Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require json
proc coread {reqBytes} {
  set ::extMsg {}
  set remBytes $reqBytes
  while {![chan eof stdin]} {
    yield
    append ::extMsg [set data [read stdin $remBytes]]
    set remBytes [expr {$remBytes - [string length $data]}]
    if {$remBytes == 0} {
      return $reqBytes
    }
  }
  throw {COREAD EOF} "Unexpected EOF"
}

proc ExtRead {} {
  chan event stdin readable coro_stdin
  while {1} {
    set ::extMsg {}
    chan puts $::fp_log "starting coread 4"
    if { [coread 4] != 4 || [binary scan $::extMsg iu len] != 1 } {
      exit
    }
    if { [coread $len] != $len } {
      exit
    }
    set msg [::json::json2dict $::extMsg]
    set book [dict get $msg book]
    set path "../${book}.html"
    set fp [open $path w]
    chan puts $fp [dict get $msg doc]
    close $fp
  }
}

proc CloseConnect {} {
  set ::forever 0
}

proc Listen {} {
  # Listening on stdin
  set ::forever 1
  chan configure stdin -buffering full -blocking 0 -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf
  coroutine coro_stdin ExtRead
  vwait forever
}

set extMsg {}
Listen
```

Comment: Why does your code contain `-encoding iso8859-1` if, according to the documentation you quoted, the encoding is UTF-8?

Comment: @Abra If use utf-8 then the `coread` does not complete and waits for more data to arrive. That might be the issue in that all the data was sent, of course, and I can see that `$len` is the same for utf-8 and iso8859-1 but the coread must be counting differently. Perhaps, it's the `[string length data]` and I need to use `[string bytelength data]`. Thanks a lot; I'll give that a try now.

Comment: @Abra That was the issue. In `proc coread`, the `if {$remBytes == 0}` had to be changed to `if {$remBytes <= 0}` because for some reason I don't know, after reading the first 4 bytes, `$remBytes` is `-1`.  However, after reading the message `$len` that those 4 bytes represent, `$remBytes` is exactly `0`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really want to answer my own question but this is too much for a comment; and I'll be happy to delete it if someone provides a better one.

As @Abra pointed out, I had the encoding configured wrong on `stdin`. I thought all that needed done then was to use `[string bytelength $data]` instead of `[string length $data]` but that only worked for a few iterations. I do not understand why `[coread 4]` was ending up reading more than 4 bytes such that `$remBytes` was negative. It resulted in misreading the data and the coroutine waited for far more data than there was. So, I moved the configuring of `stdin` into `proc extRead` and changed it from binary to utf-8 for each part of the read. Binary for the 4 bytes indicating the length of the message, and utf-8 for the message. And, I had to use `[string length $data]` for the binary read of 4 bytes and `[string bytelength $data]` for reading the message; and this resulted in `$remBytes` always equaling zero upon completion of reading both the length and the message, such that `if {$remBytes == 0}` works rather than needing the earlier change mentioned in my comment of `if {$remBytes <= 0}`.

It works and the Hebrew now appears correctly. But it bothers me that I don't understand why `[string bytelength $data]` would not be 4 when reading 4 bytes. I write the values out to a log/debugging file at various steps to verify this.

I should add, here, that I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73551761/trying-to-read-32-bit-unsigned-integer-in-tcl-using-binary-scan) in the past which @Schelte Bron answered but I don't think I followed his advice correctly or unknowingly reverted to an old version of my code. He recommended:

> The solution is to configure stdin to binary and then apply the utf-8
> decoding later:

I don't know why I didn't start with that but he probably provided the answer three months ago.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require json
proc coread {reqBytes readType} {
  set ::extMsg {}
  set remBytes $reqBytes
  while {![chan eof stdin]} {
    yield
    append ::extMsg [set data [read stdin $remBytes]]
    if { $readType } {
      set remBytes [expr {$remBytes - [string bytelength $data]}]
    } else {
      set remBytes [expr {$remBytes - [string length $data]}]
    }
    if {$remBytes == 0} {
      return $reqBytes
    }
  }
  throw {COREAD EOF} "Unexpected EOF"
}

proc ExtRead {} {
  chan event stdin readable coro_stdin
  while {1} {
    chan configure stdin -buffering full -blocking 0 -encoding binary
    set ::extMsg {}
    if { [coread 4 0] != 4 || [binary scan $::extMsg iu len] != 1 } {
      exit
    }
    chan configure stdin -buffering full -blocking 0 -encoding utf-8 -translation crlf
    if { [coread $len 1] != $len } {
      exit
    }
    set msg [::json::json2dict $::extMsg]
    set book [dict get $msg book]
    set path "../${book}.html"
    set fp [open $path w]
    chan puts $fp [dict get $msg doc]
    close $fp
  }
}

proc CloseConnect {} {
  set ::forever 0
}

proc Listen {} {
  # Listening on stdin
  set ::forever 1
  coroutine coro_stdin ExtRead
  vwait forever
}

set extMsg {}
Listen
```

Comment: I've seen `string bytelength` used correctly exactly once in my career, and that was in a place where I was allocating a static buffer of memory in some assembly code that I was generating that needed to hold a string specifically in Tcl's internal (almost UTF-8) encoding and the string was not under my control.  I was *really* surprised when that came up! The rest of the time, `string length` (and maybe `encoding convertto`, depending on what you really mean) are the answer.

Comment: Also, answering your own question is very much encouraged here _provided it really is an answer_. Yours looks fine.